# Footer's template is always on bottom of screen

Tags: css, templates, bootstrap-4

I'm not so well in web design. But now I'm using Robust Bootstrap 4 template for my project. I have a problem.

The footer's position is depended on the content above it.

I have read some answers in this site which involve many CSS configurations. I am worried that it could influence the template. Is there any simple tricky solution for me?

**EDIT:**

[image]

I am not sure to post the code because of its complexity.

Comment: post the code, it would be a guess in the dark without it

Answer (score 0):

BINGO! I just found a solution. Just adding css `min-height: 95%` to the content, and it works like a charm. 
[image]